# Please Help Me Break Down This Sentence "엄마가 다그치는 바람에 어쩔 수 없이 사실을 털어놓았다"

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice

i already know:

엄마 - mother

어쩔 수 없다 - inevitable/ can't be helped

사실 - the truth

what are:

다그치?

바람에 (the wind?)

털어놓았다?

Comment: [다그치다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=63281&nation=eng), 
[바람](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=58172), 
[털어놓다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=80103&nation=eng), and 
[-았-](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=66954&nation=eng)

Answer (score 1):

다그치다 : urge; press. to demand and rush a task, action.
ex) 사실을 말하라고 다그치다 / 범죄자를 다그치다

바람 : A bound noun used to indicate that what was just mentioned is the reason for the following proposition. It is used -는 바람에.
ex) 수업에 늦은 바람에 선생님께 혼났다 / 갑자기 비가 오는 바람에 옷이 다 젖었다.

털어놓다 : confide; confess
ex) 불만을 털어놓다 / 비밀을 털어놓다 / 솔직하게 털어놓아 봐. 어제 왜 울었어?